# How Do I Stop Progress Bar in Custom Action in Wix Installer Closing the Dialog Box

Tags: wix, windows-installer, progress-bar, custom-action, wix3.7

I have written the Progress bar code in C++ and have integrated that dll in my Custom Action code in Wix , Here is what i wrote in WIX for Proceed Button and it's Custom Action

```
<Control Id="proceedButton" Type="PushButton" Text="[Proceed]" Height="62" Width="222" X="90" Y="180" Bitmap="yes">
      <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="RegistrationInfoCustomAction">1</Publish>
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>


 <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.RegistrationInfoCustomAction.TargetDir)$(var.RegistrationInfoCustomAction.TargetName).dll"/>
<CustomAction Id="RegistrationInfoCustomAction" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="CAProgress"  />
```

The code for my dll is present here on MSDN - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367525(v=vs.85).aspx

On click of Proceed button a new dialog appears with control action progress bar -

```
<Control Id="InfoText" Type="Text" X="50" Y="30" Width="200" Height="17">
 <Subscribe Event="ActionData" Attribute="Text" />
```

```
<Control Id="ProgressBar" Type="ProgressBar" X="20" Y="115" Width="330" Height="10" ProgressBlocks="yes" Text="Hello">
 <Subscribe Event="SetProgress" Attribute="Progress" />
</Control>
```

Two Issues are -

1. Progress Bar does not fill 100%
2. After Progress Bar fills the dialog box closes automatically. Even though i have tried using Modeless="yes" and KeepModeless="no" all combinations of it.

Can you please let me know how should i solve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just place the show tag of the Next Dialog in the same Dialog where you have kept the control for Progress bar.
This will definitely work.

Comment: Can you please provide more details?